# Is the Go Appengine tutorial missing LoginURL redirect statements?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm not getting redirected to the Google account sign-in screen when I run the demo code.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/getting-started/authenticating-users

The tutorial mentions: "Note that if the user is not signed in, an HTTP status code of 302 Found redirects the browser to the Google account sign-in screen."

```
   func sign(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {  
        // [START new_context]  
        c := appengine.NewContext(r)  
        // [END new_context]         
        g := Greeting{  
                Content: r.FormValue("content"),  
                Date:    time.Now(),  
        }  
        // [START if_user]  
        if u := user.Current(c); u != nil {  
                g.Author = u.String()  
        }  
        key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "Greeting", guestbookKey(c))  
        _, err := datastore.Put(c, key, &g)  
        if err != nil {  
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)  
                return  
        }
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
        // [END if_user]    
   }
```

Source code:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-go/blob/part4-usingdatastore/hello.go

It seems something is missing e.g.:

```
if u == nil {
                url, _ := user.LoginURL(ctx, "/")
                fmt.Fprintf(w, `<a href="%s">Sign in or register</a>`, url)
                return
        }
```

If I'm wrong, how does the current code redirect user to the sign-in screen?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. To log in a user, you'll have to redirect them to a `LoginURL` as above. Once a user accesses this URL, app engine will let them log in using their google account.

However, the example code you've linked above does not require a user to be logged in. If a user is logged in, the code gets their ID and uses that as the greeting's author. If not, it just calls the user anonymous, as per the template:

```
{{with .Author}}
  <p><b>{{.}}</b> wrote:</p>
{{else}
  <p>An anonymous person wrote:</p>
{{end}}
```

Comment: The tutorial code doesn't include a way for a user to login.

Comment: You've already got that part right in your question. Use the `LoginURL` function from the `user` package and write it to the index page template. Userscan click that to log in.